# How do I set up a keyboard shortcut for Kate?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I'm running Gnome. How do I set up a keyboard shortcut to run Kate?

Answer (score 4):

Go to *Keyboard Shortcuts* in *System settings*, then press Add button and insert a Name of your choice, say "Editor", and `kate` as command then press Apply button.

Now, in the *Custom Shortcuts* section you will find an entry

```
Editor | Disabled
```

Click on disabled, then perform your custom shortcut. Press close, you're done.

Comment: Good lord, I feel like a fool. That was so easy! Thanks very much for your help, that worked beautifully.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you can consider accepting it.